# Readiness probe failing when second pod gets scheduled to the same node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8s service which maps to pod deployment with 2 replicas and is exposed as clusterIp service. I am seeing an issue when the 2nd pod gets scheduled to the same node the readiness probe (http call to an api in container port) is failing with "unable to connect error" . Is this due to some port conflict?

Deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/app-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: demo
        image: demo-app-image:1.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthcheck
            port: 8081
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthcheck
            port: 8081
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /config/app

      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: demo-configmap
          items:
          - key: config
            path: config.json
      nodeSelector:
        usage: demo-server
```

Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-service
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: demo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: demo
  ports:
    - name: admin-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 26001
      targetPort: 8081
```

Comment: Pod's port and Node's port are independent of each other.

Comment: Check the pod's log for errors. If any, add the log to the question body too.

Comment: Your cluster is local environment or cloud? Its Minikube, Kubeadm or something else? What K8s version are you using? Could you provide outout of `kubectl descirbe po <issued-podname> -n demo`, what events are there, something with mounting volume?